# How to make a link apply only to the parent element of a nested div?

Tags: html, css

I want to add a link to the button, but not the label elements.

I tried to disable them using a class but it doesn't work unless it's applied to a (link) tags only (i.e, a.disabled), and even then, it disables the button's link as well.

There's literally nothing I can add to this. It's a simple question. I just cannot get good answers on Google.

```css
@keyframes show-label {
    from {
        opacity: 0%;
    }

    to {
        opacity: 100%;
    }
}


body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex: auto;
    align-items: center;
}

div.button {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    flex: auto;
    width: 20vw;
    height: 20vw;
    background-color: lightgray;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.label {
    opacity: 0%;
}

.label:hover {
    animation: show-label 500ms forwards;
}

div.label {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
}

p.label {
    color: white;
    font-size: min(1.8vw, 18.17px);
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet"
              href="style.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <a href="#">
            <div class="button"
                 style="max-width: 157.39px; max-height: 157.39px;">
                <div class="label">
                    <p class"label">the big</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've wrapped both the button and its label in an `<a>` tag and it's nothing like *adding a link to the button*. Please describe the style you want more clearly. **Link** in not a style.

If you want the `link` to be on `button` only, you can take the `label` out.
I suggest this structure and style for what I understood from your question and it changes your structure:

```css
@keyframes show-label {
    from {
        opacity: 0%;
    }
    
    to {
        opacity: 100%;
    }
}


body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex: auto;
    align-items: center;
}

div.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    flex: auto;
    width: 20vw;
    height: 20vw;
    background-color: lightgray;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

a.button {
    height: 100%;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

a.button:hover {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.label {
    opacity: 0%;
}

.label:hover {
    animation: show-label 500ms forwards;
}

div.label {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
}

p.label {
    color: white;
    font-size: min(1.8vw, 18.17px);
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet"
              href="style.css">
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper" style="max-width: 157.39px; max-height: 157.39px;">
            <a href="#" class="button">
            </a>
            <div class="label">
                <p class="label">the big</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

**NOTE:** Do not hard code *styles* in your `html` when you have a style sheet, I left the `style="max-width: 157.39px; max-height: 157.39px;` as it was in your `html` but it's better to move it to the `style.css` file.

Comment: I can't just take the label out of the divider, because then the hover animation doesn't work, and I have to mess with positioning for it to look like it's on the div and not under it. That's my problem. It might just not be possible to fix.

Comment: The `hover` animation on the `label` is as it was. Your `button` didn't have any animations. I've just added a `background-color` change on `hover` to show it's a different element. You can set any `hover` animation you want. I still don't know if you want them to look like one element on `hover` or not. You need to Explain what you want a bit better.

Comment: I just edited the answer to contain code snippet so that you can see the result here.

Comment: The animations are working fine in the original code, I just wanted to get rid of/disable the links in the label divider and the label paragraph, so that you cant click them to get to the link destination, just the button itself would take you there. I realize it's kinda useless to add now since the label is sort of apart of the button anyway, but it's still useful to know I think, if it's actually possible.

Comment: I see why you think that's what I was having issues with though, I should've gotten rid of the hover animation since it isn't really the focus of the question.

Comment: I forgot that I left the hover animation there because I thought it could conflict with answer styles if people answering didn't know it's connected to the button.

Comment: Can't edit my last comment, I didn't get to confirm my edit and it just disappeared. Sorry.

Comment: Let me ask the question one more time. You just want the link to be disabled on label, and the animations are not the main point, did I get it right? I can suggest using `pointer-events: none;` on your `label` but this will disable the `hover` too. Does it help?

Comment: Yeah your right. I think it might just not be possible to disable links for child elements while leaving the parent element's link enabled.  Should I check your answer so that my question gets closed or would that be confusing? Can I close it another way?

Comment: You can check the answer if it's the correct answer to your question. If you've come to a conclusion to your own question you can add an answer yourself and mark it as the best answer. You don't need to delete it unless you see a problem with the question and you'r worried it might ruin your reputation or something like that :).